# Preventing error from being thrown in child swf

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to load user submitted swf files into a parent Flex application. I'll be loading the swf from a different sandbox and i will deliberately not be granting security access.

Often flash applications will have functions that try to access the stage, and in this case the child swf would throw an error because it would not have access.

I want to prevent such errors in the child swfs from causing actionscript debug error windows to pop up. Does anyone know if this is possible, with code in my parent app?

Answer (score 1):

Flash Player 10.1 can do this!
http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2009/10/global_error_handling_in_air_20.html